# How to save my data permanently with realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

What I have to do, that realm saves the date permanent?

In my little test app, I save a text from the user with realm, but when I stop the app and restart it, the data is away. When I just minimize the app or go to another view and than back, the data is there.

This is my TableView where I want to show the entries, with an add button to add entries.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class MediUserlistViewController: UITableViewController {


    var userLists = try! Realm().objects(UserListClass).sorted("UserListName")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userLists.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let userList = userLists[indexPath.row] as UserListClass
        cell.textLabel?.text = userList.UserListName
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func addList(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Neue Liste", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            alert -> Void in
            let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
            if(textField.text != ""){
                let realm = try! Realm()
                let newList = UserListClass ()
                newList.UserListName = textField.text!
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(newList)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        })

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Name der Liste"
        }

        alertController.addAction(saveAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

this is the class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
class UserListClass: Object {
    dynamic var UserListName = ""
    let Medis = List<MediClass>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "UserListName"
    }
}
```

Comment: `let realm = try! Realm()` create the file in the default directory. Default directory is `/Documents/default.realm`. You can see it `print(realm.path)`. How did you check that it has not been saved? Could you check output when executing `print(realm.objects(LastName))`?

Comment: I edit my question with the whole code of the table view. And edit the question.

Comment: I think it should work. Is there a code that delete the data? If not, to make sure when data is go away, could you write and check output of `print(realm.objects(UserListClass))` ?

Comment: I added it in the the tableview in the section `viewDidLoad`, when I start the app, I get: `Results<UserListClass> ()` When I add a entry and switches the views I get: `Results<UserListClass> (0] UserListClass {UserListName = test;Medis = RLMArray <0x15607690> ();})` When I now quit the app and restart it, the result is empty again.

Comment: Could you share your example project?

Comment: Can I send you a Dropbox link directly? I have API connections in the code which I don't want to share in the public for the moment.

Comment: Yes. Please send to help@realm.io

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102999/discussion-between-laire-and-kishikawa-katsumi).